# How to get keypress event in listview searchbox

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

in a mobile application, I have a ListView with searchbox, I would like it when the user types a barcode and presses Enter in the searchbox, the system does a specific search.
I don't know how to capture the keypress in the searchbox, can anyone help me please?

In the search box the user can search for the description that already works, and can capture through a bar code scanner, so it is necessary to search by code only after the Enter is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Both OneKeyDown and OnKeyPress will help you achieve the goal, although they are slightly different.

In Events, add an OnKeyDown/OnKeyPress event, such as srchbx1KeyDown/srchbx1KeyPress.

In code, implement this event such as:

```
procedure TForm1.srchbx1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
     ShowMessage('RETURN down');
end;
```

or

```
procedure TForm1.srchbx1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then
     ShowMessage('Enter pressed');
end;
```

Comment: This code does not work in firemonkey, the operation of the virtual keyboard is different in mobile.